# How do I generate a list of all possible permutations of a vector of numbers (N) taken (n) at a time in R with additional constraints?

Tags: r

For example, Suppose I want to generate all possible permutations in the series 1:10 taken 3 at a time. But, the 3 numbers chosen have to be in ascending order. Hence, 3,4,5 is acceptable but not 5,4,3. The second condition is that they can't have jumps, they have to be consecutive in order. Hence, 1,2,4 is unacceptable. How to get this in R?

Comment: Perhaps `m1 <- t(combn(1:10, 3));
 m1[m1[,1] < m1[,2] & m1[,2] < m1[,3],]`

Comment: But this is generating even those permutations which are not consecutive like 1,2,7. I want it to be exactly  adjacent to each others.i.e, not a gap of more than 1 between the numbers.

Comment: I posted a solution based on your comment.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

We can create the combinations of numbers using `combn`, then subset the columns by creating a logical index by checking the difference of the rows are equal to 1, and transpose the output

```
m1 <- combn(1:10, 3)
t(m1[,colSums(diff(m1)==1)==2])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    5    6
#[5,]    5    6    7
#[6,]    6    7    8
#[7,]    7    8    9
#[8,]    8    9   10
```

Comment: It would be interesting to watch your algorithm applied to the case where, say, n=1000 and k=500, for which the output consists of only 501 sequences :-).

Comment: I tried that and its gigantic :). What if the seq is not from 1:10, rather from any number like 200 to 210 and I need all the permutations of size greater than a particular n, say 10?

Comment: @AKR  I haven't tested the benchmarks, if you feel that the other solution is more efficient, you choose that one.  My solution was based on the example you showed

Comment: @akrun it's logically brilliant. My task was for a limited range of numbers. So, it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun I generated all the permutations for the series 2000:2016 taken equal to or more than 2 at a time based on your commands using this loop:                                                    for (i in 1:16) {
  m1=combn(2000:2016, i+1)
  m2=m1[,colSums(diff(m1))==i]
  print(m2)
}

Answer (score 2):

These consist of the sequences 1:3, 2:4, ..., 8:10.  In general, to obtain all such subsequences of length `k` among 1:n, you can start with the smallest 1:k and keep adding 1 to its elements:

```
subseq <- function(n,k) if (1 <= k && k <= n) outer(1:k, 0:(n-k), "+")
```

The sequences are in the columns, already in lexicographic order.  Since no sorting is actually done, this is a O(kn) algorithm, which is asymptotically optimal.

Example: `subseq(10,3)` produces

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

A slightly faster `R` implementation might avoid `outer` like this:

```
subseq <- function(n=10, k=3) if (1 <= k && k <= n)  matrix(rep(0:(n-k), each=k), k) + 1:k
```

Comment: How do I solve the issue using similar commands if the seq is not from 1:10, rather from any number like 200 to 210 and I need all the permutations of size greater than a particular n, say 10?

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question, but the first part has an easy answer: generate the sequences from 1 through 11 and then add 199 to them.